# SharePoint Forms Authentication Provider Name Prefix on Username

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I have setup a SharePoint site with forms authentication and My Sites. The users username displays correctly on the main site collection, however whent he user creates a My Site the user is always referred to as : for example it might be:

sqlMembershipProvider:testuser

This can be seen in this image:

http://img141.imageshack.us/img141/464/mysite.jpg

How do I remove the sqlMemberProvider from the users visible name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the fact that you have Enabled the FBA in MySite I am sure, you would have gone through following links.

1. [Exclusive Site on FBA & SharePoint](http://www.sharepointfba.com/)
2. [Configuring FBA in MySite](http://www.devcow.com/blogs/jdattis/archive/2007/03/01/Office-SharePoint-Server-2007-Forms-Based-Authentication-FBA-w-MySites-Walkthrough-Part-2.aspx)

One know restriction with the FBA Based SharePoint is that SharePoint has no out of the Box way to Import the User Profile details from the FBA DB, as it does in the Active Directory. So when you enable the My Site with FBA it uses user name (That has Provider:Username format) in all the places instead of the Name. To overcome this what we have done is to create the User Profile using code and update the Display Name so that we get the Names as we wanted with out the Provider prefix.

You can refer [this](http://sridharu.blogspot.com/2008/03/create-user-profiles-with-forms.html) for creating the UserPorfile using Code.

Comment: Thanks for this, I found change the PersonalSpace property changes most of the usernames. The last problem is to remove the prefix from the URL to the My Site.